# How to apply a SPSS date transformation formula to multiple variables?

Tags: r, date, transform, spss

I'm relatively new to R and am trying to find out how to convert specific colums which contain dates in a large dataframe I imported from SPSS. 241 out of 604 variables are dates, which R displays as seconds from 1582-10-14. I succesfully transformed one such column using the as.Date function

```
dataframe$column.date <- as.Date(dataframe$column.date / 86400, origin = "1582-10-14")
```

How would I go about applying this function to these specific 241 / 604 colums in my dataframe without having to write out 240 additional lines of code?

[image: Part of the dataframe]

Comment: Hi  welcome to SO, do the dates column have some logic that is unique to them, like the "date" on col name, or only them are over >1000 or all dates between (12000,13000) or anythong like that?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick reaction. The names of the colums which contain the dates don't have a logic to them unfortunately. However, the dates are the only high values in my dataframe. No other value surpasses 100.

Comment: @Superschmiecht can you please paste a screenshot how the dataframe looks like

Comment: I added a screenshot of 2 colums which include dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that this is the sample of the data.frame that you have.

```
record_createdon<-c(13794833494,13794833494,13794837926)
inclusion<-c('Yes,','Yes','Yes')
ibd_dat<-c(12866169600,13556937600,13552272000)

df<-data.frame(record_createdon,inclusion,ibd_dat)
```

According to what you have done-creating a vector with the names of columns containing the date. Lets call this `date_vec`

`date_vec<-c('record_createdon','ibd_dat')`

you can use the lapply function in base R to convert the columns with dates without having to write a conversion for each column with a data using the following

```
df[date_vec]<-lapply(df[date_vec],function(x) as.Date(x/86400, origin = "1582-10-14"))

  record_createdon inclusion    ibd_dat
1       2019-12-04      Yes, 1990-07-01
2       2019-12-04       Yes 2012-05-21
3       2019-12-04       Yes 2012-03-28
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it applies the function to all other variables as well. Is there a way to specify which variables the command should apply to?

Comment: are the non date values in a specific order? e.g every other column

Comment: Unfortunately they are not. However, I did make a vector containing the names of all columns which include dat values. Is there a way to make R apply the function above to only those columns? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Superschmiecht updated the answer based on the new information

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we can solve that using the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)


logic <- function(x){
  mean_x = mean(x,na.rm = TRUE)
  mean_x %>% is.na() %>% `!` & mean_x > 100
}

date_conversion <- function(x){
  as.Date(x/86400, origin = "1582-10-14")
}

new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate_if(logic,.funs = date_conversion)
```

Comment: This works and mutates all values above 100 using the function given. However, this only works when I run these commands. When I print the dataframe afterwards, it still gives the dates as high numbers instead of the YYYY-MM-DD format. Is there a way to save the changes in the dataframe?

Comment: @Superschmiecht look into assignment in R